# File.WriteAllBytes : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Folder\file.png", bytes);
```

works fine

```
File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\Folder\\file.png", bytes);
```

returns **The given path's format is not supported**

The problem is that I'm using the `File.WriteAllBytes` function from an `ASP MVC` project and I'm loading the path from a `web.config` file.

```
<add key="Path" value="‪D:\Folder"/>
```

So in my controller code I have

```
File.WriteAllBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"], bytes);
```

and

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]
```

returns

> ‪D:\\Folder

so I have the error : **`The given path's format is not supported`**

Comment: if you're reading the directory from the config... where and when are you adding the file name and extension that creates the entire path?

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("D:\Folder\file.png", bytes); works fine ` - I very much doubt that.And your Path in `AppSettings` needs to be the complete path including file name - or have the file name added to this path using `Path.Combine`.

Comment: What's up with your profile pic? E: it's a `Hat` whatever that is?

Comment: I've forgot to write the filename in my post but I have it in my code. (I've edited my post)

Comment: @LocEngineer Yes File.WriteAllBytes("D:\Folder\file.png", bytes); doesn't work.. I have edited my post.

Comment: Biggest problem: this is MVC, i.e. a web application. It does not have access permission to your D drive. Write it in App_Data in your web folder instead.

Comment: @ptiflo you have the file name in the WriteAllBytes method but not in your web.config key's value - Have you added it here?